# Loss of digits when dividing floats C++ (Arduino)

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get a gps reading from a string to a float on my Arduino. The string has all handles all of the digits just fine, but when I divide it to get a float I lose 4 of my digits. Here is my code:

```
gpsStrings[0].replace(".", "");
lat = gpsRawData[0].toFloat();
lat = lat / 1000000.0;
```

Using .toFloat on a string that still has the decimal point in it results in the same thing, only two numbers after the decimal point.

Example numbers:

```
42427898 :: 42.43 - what happens
42427898 :: 42.427898 - what I want to happen
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I was wrong, the default print function only uses two digits of precision. So I had to add how many digits I wanted to the statement.

```
print(lat, 20);
```

Will give 20 digits of precision on the serial monitor where

```
print(lat)
```

only gives two.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Double instead of a float.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision#Double-precision_examples for more information.

Comment: I get the same result. On Arduino doubles aren't more accurate than floats. They can hold the same number of digits. http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double

Comment: I see, That is quite unfortunate.. Thanks for the tip